# What is the meaning of these "paint reasons" in a blink browser?

Tags: google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, blink, web-performance

I was making a graphics heavy site which I tried profiling using the Timeline Tool in Google Chrome, but I'm unable to understand why such vast areas away from the viewport get painted..

Could you please help me in undertanding the reasons below?

> Might overlap other composited content

---

> Cannot be squashed because this layer has a different clipping
>   container than the squashing layer

---

> Cannot be squashed as the squashing layer would become too sparse

If not atleast help me understand what is meant by "squashed layer" or clipping?

**PS:** 
I've recorded timeline data if it helps : [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xcn4nenwwz61k5/TimelineRawData-20151127T235859.json.zip?dl=0) . The website I'm profiling for is [iimc-carpediem.com/2016alpha](http://iimc-carpediem.com/2016alpha/)